# finalize() timed out after 30 seconds

Tags: java, android, timeoutexception, finalize

I'm seeing few crashes in fabric which looks like this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.text.TextPaint.finalize() timed out after 30 seconds
       at android.graphics.Paint.finalizer(Paint.java)
       at android.graphics.Paint.finalize(Paint.java:2437)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.io.FileInputStream.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at java.io.FileDescriptor.valid(FileDescriptor.java:87)
       at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:37)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:121)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:142)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I'm not sure why and which code of my Android app causes these crashes, I am not able to replicate it as well. Maybe someone of you had similar issue and solve it?

Comment: The fact that a finalizer is trying to close your `FileInputStream` means that you forgot to close it yourself. You should use try-with-resoruces whenever you open a file, to ensure that the input stream is always closed correctly.

Comment: Yes, it might be, but it seems it is caused by one of the libraries because I can't find any usage of FileInputStream in my app.